# How to fix vertical in file Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

i am trying to reopen this Crystal Report file after i reset the window i get this error. I've tried deleting my version of Crystal Report and reinstalling it, but that doesn't work either. I also tried deleting references and re-adding it, but it didn't work. can anyone help me to solve this problem. thanks in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuMaS.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than double-clicking the RPT file, open it from within Crystal Reports. It looks like the app associated with .rpt is a hex editor.